# Display Html page inside overlay using qtip2

Tags: jquery, html, qtip2

I am trying to display a html page inside an overlay on top of my current page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztVS7.jpg
This is a picture to demonstrate what i'm after, The white page is the overlay i would like to place over the top of my webpage and it is offset to the right to take up the space without covering the menu on the left.

After some research i figure the best bet would be qtip2 however I cannot get it to work correctly.

When the tooltip does load i get a parse xml error tooltip.. I figure if i can just get it to pop the content then i can go about styling it correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
 {
     // MAKE SURE YOUR SELECTOR MATCHES SOMETHING IN YOUR HTML!!!
     $('.changePage').qtip({
       content: {
         text: function(event, api) {
           $.ajax({
             url: element.data('url') // Use data-url attribute for the URL
           })
           .then(function(content) {
             
             // Set the tooltip content upon successful retrieval
             api.set('content.text', content);
           }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Upon failure... set the tooltip content to the status and error value
                api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
            });

            return 'Loading...'; // Set some initial text
        }
    }
 });
 });
```

```css
.block:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 color: #BE1E2D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" id = "change1">
  <a href='change.html' class = "changePage"></a>
  
  <div class="big-text">Popup</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few mistakes. First you need to place your text in between your `a` tags so that when you hover it, the function can run. Then your `element` variable is not being defined because you first need to all the `api` variable. Try this code. It should work:

HTML:

```
<div class="block" id ="change1">
    <a data-url="change.html" class="changePage">Popup</a>
    <div class="big-text"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.changePage').qtip({
    content: {
        text: function(event, api) {
            $.ajax({
                url: api.elements.target.data('url')
            }).done(function(html) {
                api.set('content.text', html);
            }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
            });
            return 'Loading...';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, However now I get a Parse Error. The tooltip says "Parse error invalid XML"

Comment: is `change.html` located on the same directory? does it have `html, document, body` tags?

Comment: Correct it is in the same directory and also has all those tags..It is almost identical to my index.html

Comment: I would be open to another way to get the same effect? If there is a better way.

Comment: I think thats the problem.. qtip is not designed to display those html tags. It will probably just display anything inside the `body` tag. is it possible for you to remove all those tags out?

Comment: I shall give it a go and report back

Comment: by removing most of the content it's now able to show some of it... Could you direct as to how to position the popup now? Would it be in the script itself or in the css?

Comment: how do you want to position it?

Comment: Like in the picture http://i.imgur.com/ykwrlg0.jpg The right side of the page with the white background is how i want it to show regardless of the content inside.. Then i can build the html page that will be shown around it. Does that make sense? When i click popup i want that white overlay to popup and show whatver is in my change.html file.

Comment: let me see what i can do. hold on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70895/discussion-between-mike-and-codegodie).